# Derivative of $s = u^2 \iff\sqrt s = u$

Tags: calculus

Suppose we have $s = u^2 \iff\sqrt s = u$.

Then taking the derivatives result in different things even thus $s$ takes on the same value for every $u$.

Comment: What are you differentiating with respect to?

Comment: Im differentiating with respect to $s$.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Actually, they do:
$$
s=u^2\\
\sqrt s=u
$$
Differentiating:
$$
ds=2u\,du\\
\frac{ds}{2\sqrt s}=du
$$
Now, we can substitute $s=u^2$ in the second equation:
$$
du=\frac{ds}{2\sqrt u}=\frac{ds}{2u}
$$
Thus, we get $ds=2u\,du$ again.

This is true for any function $f(x)$ with inverse $g(x)=f^{-1}(x)$.
(using the chain-rule)
$$
f'(g(x))g'(x)=\frac{d}{dx}f(g(x))=\frac{dx}{dx}=1
$$
Solving for $g'(x)$ gives
$$
g'(x)=\frac1{f'(g(x))}
$$

Comment: Some of the other answers point out that I can just replace $u$ by $s^{1/2}$, but then I could also replace by $-s^{1/2}$ ? Your proof is very clear and rigorous I think, and you justify they are equal by substituting $s$ by $u^2$ which is true for the equation you are working with ?

Answer (score 3):

Taking the [differental](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Differential_%28infinitesimal%29)

$$s=u^2\Rightarrow ds=2udu$$
and
$$\sqrt s= u\Rightarrow \frac{ds}{2\sqrt s}=du\iff \frac{ds}{2u}=du\iff ds=2udu$$
so we find the same result.

Answer (score 2):

First yields $ds=2u\,du$.

Second yields $\displaystyle\frac{ds}{2\sqrt s}=du$. Substituting $\sqrt s=u$ will give the same as the first one.

Answer (score 1):

Well, $$1 = \frac{d}{ds} s = \frac{d}{ds} u^2 = 2u \frac{du}{ds} \implies \frac{du}{ds} = \frac{1}{2u}= \frac{1}{2s^{1/2}}$$

On the other hand, $$\frac{du}{ds} = \frac{d}{ds} s^{1/2} = \frac{1}{2s^{1/2}}$$ as before.

Comment: Thanks for your great and simple answer. May I ask why you may substitute $u$ for $s^{1/2}$ and not by $-s^{1/2}$ ?

Answer (score -1):

Because $s=u^2\iff \sqrt{s}=|u|$, so your assumption is just wrong.

Edit, using Ragnar's answer:
From differentiation of 
$$
s=u^2\quad\text{vs}\quad
\sqrt s=u
$$
we have
$$
ds=2u\,du\quad\text{vs}\quad
\frac{ds}{2\sqrt s}=du.
$$
Substititing $s=u^2$ in the last equation yields
$$
du=\frac{ds}{2\sqrt{ u^2}}=\frac{ds}{2|u|}
$$
Thus, we don't get $ds=2u\,du$.

Comment: Dear @Michael : While the OP's use of $\iff$ here isn't optimal, it did get the idea across that they are examining two forms of the same equation and encountered trouble in the bookkeeping. There isn't really much wrong with what they wrote, and the tone and content of this solution are not really helpful :( Any chance you might rewrite/delete? Regards

Comment: @rschwieb Regarding the tone: what grade of politeness is necessary to call a false claim be  false?  Regarding the helpfulness  of the solution: I've given a hint to resolve the contradiction observed by the OP.

Comment: Dear Michael: Sure, the iff is not really the right thing to write here. But from the context it rather looks like a poor choice of statement rather than a false claim. There's nothing wrong with saying "look at $u=\sqrt{s}$. Then also $u^2=s$. I think these should produce the same implicit derivative... where did I go wrong?" At any rate, thanks for improving the post... it's much better!

Comment: Dear Michael : Oh yes, and saying "I think part of the question as stated is false" is a great comment, but solutions that are basically surly versions of "your question is wrong" are not worth posting, really. Not unless the poster is *really* asking for it :)

Comment: @rschwieb The OP stated: “Then taking the derivatives result in different things even thus $s$ takes on the same value for every $u$." IMHO there's a question implied; my answer was: “Because $s=u^2\iff \sqrt{s}=|u|$, so your assumption is just wrong."  So what's wrong with my answer?

Comment: I will say for a *third* time that I don't think the user knew what they were writing when they used $\iff$. I'm pretty sure they just meant to say "$s=u^2$ comes about from $\sqrt{s}=u$". I haven't at any point disagreed with you about the inaccurateness of the OP's way of expressing the two equations. I disagreed with the utility of a solution that said basically "your question is wrong because your assumptions are wrong," but you have already fixed that, so I have nothing to complain about :) I am not the downvoter and I'm not the delete voter, btw.